# How can I accept negative values as the inputs in Python?

Tags: python

How can I accept negative values as the inputs?

```
import math
x_coordinates = input("Enter the x coordinates: ")
y_coordinates = input("Enter the y coordinates: ")

x_coordinates = [int(x) for x in x_coordinates]
y_coordinates = [int(x) for x in y_coordinates]

total_x = (x_coordinates[-1] - x_coordinates[0]) ** 2
total_y = (y_coordinates[-1] - y_coordinates[0]) ** 2
total = total_x + total_y
total = math.sqrt(total)
print(total)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What was the input format for positive coordinates? Each digit is a separate coordinate?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide test input.

Comment: And what do you want the input format to be? Comma separated or space separated, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're entering input such as `1 -42 14` or something similar. `input()` returns a string. When you do `[int(x) for x in x_coordinates]`, you are calling `int()` on each character in the string. So, you should `.split()` the string on spaces first, then call `int()` on each member:

```
x_coordinates = [int(x) for x in x_coordinates.split()]
```

Given the above input, this would return

```
[1, -42, 14]
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something that would split up the inputs and used this method multiple times, but just didn't know where to exactly locate it. Thank you it did help!

Answer (score 0):

`input` gives you one string, and when you iterate over that, you get each character separately. Come up with a separator character, like space, and split the inputs on that:

```py
import math

x_coordinates = input("Enter the x coordinates: ")
y_coordinates = input("Enter the y coordinates: ")

x_coordinates = [int(x) for x in x_coordinates.split(" ")]
y_coordinates = [int(x) for x in y_coordinates.split(" ")]

total_x = (x_coordinates[-1] - x_coordinates[0]) ** 2
total_y = (y_coordinates[-1] - y_coordinates[0]) ** 2
total = total_x + total_y
total = math.sqrt(total)
print(total)
```

Then:

```
robert@here:~$ python mcve.py
Enter the x coordinates: 1 2 3
Enter the y coordinates: -1 -2 -3
2.8284271247461903
```

That said, if you only want to read 2 x and 2 y values anyway, you should probably just use separate variables.

```py
import math

x1 = int(input("Enter x1: "))
x2 = int(input("Enter x2: "))
y1 = int(input("Enter y1: "))
y2 = int(input("Enter y1: "))

total_x = (x2 - x1) ** 2
total_y = (y2 - y1) ** 2
total = total_x + total_y
total = math.sqrt(total)
print(total)
```

Or at least check how many numbers are entered and print an error.

```py
import math

x_coordinates = input("Enter the x coordinates: ")
y_coordinates = input("Enter the y coordinates: ")

x_coordinates = [int(x) for x in x_coordinates.split(" ")]
y_coordinates = [int(x) for x in y_coordinates.split(" ")]
if len(x_coordinates) > 2 or len(y_coordinates) > 2:
    print("Need 2 x and y coordinates")
else:
    total_x = (x_coordinates[-1] - x_coordinates[0]) ** 2
    total_y = (y_coordinates[-1] - y_coordinates[0]) ** 2
    total = total_x + total_y
    total = math.sqrt(total)
    print(total)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time and help! I followed everything and it did work.